# Cannot get element from Backbone template

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone template to represent a list of football players. After rendering, I modify some of the template elements by inserting other templates into it. The render() function of the view is:

```
    render: function () {
        that = this;
        this.$el.html(template(this.model.attributes));

        var homeTeam = new player.PlayerCollection({team_id: this.model.get('home_id')});

        homeTeam.fetch({
        data: { forward_first:true, exlude_keepers:true},
        processData: true,
        success:function (collection) {

            var forwards = collection.where({'position':'Forward'});
            new PlayerListGoalView({players: forwards, 
                                    position:"Forward",
                                    el: $("#home-forwards", that.el), 
                                    player_id:that.player_id
                                });


            }
        });


        this.prepareList();
    },
```

The resulting html has a series of nested lists e.g.:

```
  <ul id="expList" class="topcoat-list list">
    <li id="home-forwards">
        <ul class="topcoat-list list">

            <li class="topcoat-list__item " id="player-713">
                <span>Fabio Borini</span>    
            </li>

            <li class="topcoat-list__item " id="player-696">        
                <span>Jozy Altidore</span>
            </li>

            <li class="topcoat-list__item " id="player-697">
                <span>Mikael Mandron</span>     
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="away-forwards">

    </li>
    <li id="home-midfielders">

    </li>
    <li id="away-midfielders">

    </li>
    <li id="home-defenders">

    </li>
    <li id="away-defenders">

    </li>    
  </ul>
```

The in prepareList(), I get the main ul, and then it's li children that have ul's themselves:

```
    prepareList: function(){

        var ul = this.$('#expList');
        var el = ul.find('li:has(ul)');

        console.log('ul.length is:'); 
        console.log(ul.length);
        console.log('el.length is:'); 
        console.log(el.length);

    },
```

This results in "ul.length is:1" and "el.length is:0". So it get's the ul, but not the li.

When I expand the ul tag in chrome inspector, I can see the firstElementChild is li#home-forwards and all the innerHTML is as above. Yet it still somehow cannot get the li.

Now, if I hardcode the html above into the template, the ul and the li are both found!

Any ideas?

Comment: what's this : `$("#home-forwards", that.el)` for? shouldn't be `el:that.$(selector)`? or maybe `el : $("#home-forwards")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `this.prepareList()` inside your "success" callback.
Right now you call it when the collection was not successfully fetched yet.